# Dragging li outside of ul not visible

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, html-lists

I have a scrollable `ul`

```
<ul class="col1" id="MyID" name="MyName"> 
    <li draggable="true"  class="li-object draggable" value="@item.Id"></li>
    <li draggable="true"  class="li-object draggable" value="@item.Id"></li>
</ul>
```

and I want to be able to choose an element from the left list and drop it somewhere outside the `ul`,

```
<ul id="floor" dropzone="copy">DROP HERE</ul>
```

however when I drag an `li` outside of `ul` it is not visible (and also not visible when I drop it over the yellow area)  - see JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vehmt5x9/1/ .

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Follow basic Basic Drag and Drop at https://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/gbdwjj  this might solve your problem

Comment: remove `overflow-y: scroll;` from `ul`

Comment: I can't, I need it. I have a very long list, didn't put it all in the jsFiddle

Comment: The only way that you can move out the elements from an overflowed parent is `absolute` position on children, there is no other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else having this problem, I solved the problem using the `helper` option:

```
$(".draggable").draggable({
    appendTo: 'body',
    revert: 'invalid',
    helper: function() {
        //drag selected items
        var selected = $(this);
        var container = $('<div/>');
        container.append(selected.clone());
        return container;
     },
    stop: function () {
        $(this).draggable('option', 'revert', 'invalid');
    }
});

$( "#droppable" ).droppable({
  classes: {
    "ui-droppable-active": "ui-state-active",
    "ui-droppable-hover": "ui-state-hover"
  },
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
    $( this )
        .find( '.li-object' ).replaceWith($(ui.helper.children()))
      .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
      .find( "p" )
        .html( "Dropped!" );
  }
});
```

Updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vehmt5x9/6/